# Rails: Excel columns, seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I created an excel sheet with columns id, task, description

I find this and put it in my seeds.rb:

```
require 'spreadsheet'


Spreadsheet.open('/db/data/uebung.xls') do |uebung|
  book.worksheet('Sheet1').each do |row|
  break if row[0].nil?
  puts row.join(',')
end
end
```

I get this message:

```
  [DEPRECATED] By requiring 'parseexcel', 'parseexcel/parseexcel' and/or
         'parseexcel/parser' you are loading a Compatibility layer which
         provides a drop-in replacement for the ParseExcel library. This
         code makes the reading of Spreadsheet documents less efficient and
         will be removed in Spreadsheet version 1.0.0
```

What do you think. Is is not easy to import excel data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org) to import excel to my rails app. And it not too hard to do that. You can watch [the railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) from Ryan Bates to do it with roo if you want.

I give you my example code of roo

Gemfile

```
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'roo'
```

Controller:

```
def import
  @trainerone = Trainerone.find(params[:trainerone_id])

  Trainerone.import(params[:file], @trainerone.id)
  redirect_to @trainerone, notice: "Import Success."
end
```

Model:

```
def self.import(file, trainer_id)
  trainerone = Trainerone.find(trainer_id)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    trainer = Trainerone.create! row.to_hash
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when '.csv' then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when '.xls' then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when '.xlsx' then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag import_trainerones_path(@trainerone.id), multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

This `import_trainerones_path` was taken from your `route` which pointing at your `action: import` on your `trainerone controller` (look at the controller above)

Hope can help you..!

Comment: ok i implementet this. My controller name ist Trainerone. I dont understand this in yout form : form_tag import_sales_journal_header_sales_journal_details_path(@sales_journal_header.id). And what is SalesJournalHeader?

Comment: I just edit my answer, hope can make the case more clearly. `SalesJournalHeader` is my model so your model should be `Trainerone`.  `import_sales_journal_header_sales_journal_details_path` is from my routes, which your should be `import_trainerones_path`